# OS X El Capitan won't work and is not recognized on UniBeast

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootable-disk

I have been trying to download the new version of El Capitan and use UniBeast to create a bootable USB. However, every time I download El Capitan from the App Store, it takes 2 hours to download the 6 GB content.

The MacBook restarts and everything, but when I open it in the App Store, it gives me the option of downloading it again, as if I never downloaded it. The UniBeast can't find the El Capitan either.

Answer (score 1):

The officially supported way to create a USB OS X Installer, for OS X Mavericks and later, is to use `createinstallmedia` from within the downloaded installer application bundle.

Have a look at: [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

The following is from the link above:

> Use the 'createinstallmedia' command in Terminal
>
> 1. Download the OS X installer from the Mac App Store. Quit the installer if it opens automatically after downloading. The installer
>      will be in your Applications folder.
> 2. Mount your USB flash drive or other volume. You could also use a secondary internal partition.
> 3. Open the Terminal app, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
> 4. Use the createinstallmedia command in Terminal to create the bootable installer. Examples of this command are in the next section.
>      For detailed usage instructions, make sure that the appropriate
>      Install OS X app is in your Applications folder, then enter one of the
>      following paths in Terminal:
>
> Path for El Capitan:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
> ```
>
> Examples
>
> This is the basic syntax of the command. Replace `volumepath` with
>   the path to your USB flash drive or other volume, and replace
>   `installerpath` with the path to the Install OS X app.
>
> ```
> createinstallmedia --volume volumepath --applicationpath installerpath
> ```
>
> The following examples assume that the OS X installer is in your
>   Applications folder and the name of your USB flash drive or other
>   volume is MyVolume:
>
> Example for El Capitan:
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app
> ```

Note: You can substitute `Mavericks` or `Yosemite` for `El\ Capitan` in the above command examples.